# Update facebook follow button URL dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I got following code from facebook developer's page and it work fine:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src =   "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=916488391727774"  ;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck" data-layout="standard" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I want that whenever user update input field with his profile URL, follow button should update and display his record instead of zuck's default account. How is it possible with jquery/javascript?

Note:- I just used the above code for fb-follow button and didn't used it's API's or anything extra.

Comment: you can try this : `$('.fb-follow').attr('data-href', updatedprofileURL);`

Comment: Thanks @raveenanigam it worked. I've two more questions now:

1- when i enter invalid url it doesnot show anything, is there any way by which I can tell user to enter correct URL?

2- it is not showing faces although data-show-faces is set true.